# Rhapsody statechart code generation fails C++20 build due to concept keyword conflict

Tags: c++, rhapsody

Our project uses Rhapsody tool to generate C++ code, it is a quite legacy one and have been working fine until recently we are trying to update the compiler version to enable C++20. Generate code for statechart blocks compilation because of the bridge instance name `concept` is a reserved keyword.

Generated code looks like this:

```cpp
class MyStateChartClass : public OMComponentState {
    //...

    OMState* stHandleRequests;
};

class MyStateClass_ROOT: public OMComponentState {
    //...

/// Framework operations ///
public:
    void entState();
    
    ///...
/// Framework ///
public:
    MyStateChartClass* concept;
};
```

Is there any properties or configurations to rename the variable name from `concept` to another literal?